# Category theory and statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, category-theory

I've been juggling with some concepts from statistics revolving around properties of estimators and sufficient statistics, and I can't help but notice that they have a strong categorical flavor, e.g. I'm pretty sure minimal sufficient statistics are terminal objects in an appropriate category.

I know someone must have worked these things out but haven't been able to find it - I'd be grateful if someone could give me a pointer to some illuminating discussion of applications of category theory to statistics.

Comment: I don't think that minimal sufficience is a universal property because no uniqueness of the function is required (and in fact does not hold).

Comment: Minimal sufficient might be the coproduct of the information and equality up to isomorphism would hold?

Comment: @HeinrichD : There is uniqueness up to a simple equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2):

The following paper of T. Fritz seems to be close to what you're after, [arXiv:1908.01021](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07021). In particular the sections 14-15-16.

Answer (score 1):

If you know russian, you can have a look at the book "Ченцов Н.Н. Статистические решающие правила и оптимальные выводы". It has some info about it.